# Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.platformprovider and com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.platformprovider

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

In my android app, I use FacebookDialog.

I am writing down the following code.

In Galaxy Note3(Android4.4.2), It goes well.

However, in Experia SOL21(Android4.1.2) it doesn't. The error code is following.

[My code]
in Activity.java

```
 private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

 private void FbShare(String shareTitle, String shareUrl,String shareImageUrl) {
    if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(),
            FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
        try {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(
                    this).setDescription(shareTitle).setName(shareTitle)
                    .setLink(shareUrl).setPicture(shareImageUrl)
                    .setApplicationName("myapp").build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } catch (FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Facebook Error1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else Toast.makeText(this, "Facebook Error2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

[Error Log]

```
Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.platformprovider
Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.platformprovider
```

Plus, Toast in Activity.java says "Facebook Error2".

I properly added the internet permission to the manifest and facebookSDK metadata like following.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<meta-data
   android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
   android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: This usually means you don't have the Facebook app installed, or have an outdated version.

Comment: I got it! My Facebook app is old version. After updating, it goes well. Thank you!