# 'An error occured while executing doInBackground()' with facebook login

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to implement facebook login in my app. This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "some"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 6
    versionName "2.4"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```

And I placed the following layout where desired **(I can see the button right before the crash)**:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

And I also start the sdk like this in **onCreate** in an active activity of type FragmentActivity:

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

The errors I obtain are as follows:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

and

```
04-18 12:35:21.400    6833-7070/ E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
04-18 12:35:22.280    6833-7100/ E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
04-18 12:35:22.280    6833-7100/ E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) -
04-18 12:35:22.280    6833-7100/ D/WebKit﹕ ERROR:
04-18 12:35:22.280    6833-7100/ D/WebKit﹕ SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db
    Cause - unable to open database file
```

even though I don't use sqlite, so I suppose it has something to do with facebook...

What is missing here?

Comment: @HareshChhelana Why would the facebook app be needed? ... And do I still need to put the sdk in the app folder if I have it on gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
04-18 12:35:21.400    6833-7070/ E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
```

this is tell you ,no provider with your phone.this provider is facebook app provide

you may be install facebook app.

I search this problem，you can see

[Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670011/failed-to-find-provider-info-for-com-facebook-katana-provider-attributionidprovi)

[Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.platformprovider and com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.platformprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440272/failed-to-find-provider-info-for-com-facebook-katana-provider-platformprovider-a)

[Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523290/failed-to-find-provider-info-for-com-facebook-katana-provider-platformprovider)

so，this not your carsh cause，this only one log，check your have facebook app。
you may be check sqlite error，this your carsh cause.

but，your crash because sqlite，you can see [Android webview geoposition database failed to open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984237/android-webview-geoposition-database-failed-to-open)

I guess you use Emulator？

try

mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());